# TLP (advanced power management) on Gnome Ubuntu 17.04 on Lenovo x230

Tags: gnome, power-management, indicator, tlp

I have Lenovo X230 with Gnome Ubunutu 17.04 fresh install with all updates. I have installed TLP as per [instructions](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw 
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpitools
```

I have rebooted. But I have no icons after reboot that are expected on the top bar. I even don't know if it is working.

Could you please help with setting up TLP properly?

Comment: To determine if TLP is running, open a terminal and enter the command `sudo tlp stat | more` - I dont think any of the programs that you listed above have status tray icons.  TLP can be configured by editing the file `/etc/default/tlp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLP doesn't have a GUI, so no icons on the bar or elsewhere. See [Features](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#features).

See same instructions for [how to check](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#check).